# Rest WCF vs Web api

Tags: rest, wcf, asp.net-web-api

I read some articles and i search many about differences between `Rest WCF vs Web api` but I just find difference between `WCF vs Web api` , I find some difference:

> WCF Rest=>
>   a)It support HTTP GET and POST verbs by [WebGet] and [WebInvoke] attributes respectively.
>   b)To enable other HTTP verbs you have to do some configuration in IIS to accept request of that particular verb on .svc files. 
>   c)Passing data through parameters using a WebGet needs configuration. The UriTemplate must be specified.
>   d)It support XML, JSON and ATOM data format.

and

> WebApi=> a)Unlike WCF Rest service, it use the full featues of HTTP (like URIs, request/response headers, caching, versioning, various content formats). 
>   b)Responses are formatted by Web API’s MediaTypeFormatter into JSON, XML or whatever format you want to add as a MediaTypeFormatter.

I want know other differences between them, and when is it better to use `WebApi` and when `Rest Wcf`?

Answer (score 0):

I would say, if you start a new project and you need to expose a REST web interface in .NET, **Web API is the way to go** because AFAIK, WCF is deprecated. I would only consider to use WCF Rest if you have to expose both, SOAP and REST web interfaces.

Comment: WCF is **NOT** deprecated.  WCF is the replacement for both ASMX and .NET Remoting.  WebAPI is the generally preferred way to go for RESTful services, but for SOAP or replacements for .NET Remoting WCF is the preferred framework.

Comment: @Tim his means that for ReST ful services wcf rest is deprecated

Comment: @Martin Brandy what is your mean in this :`f you have to expose both, SOAP and REST web interfaces.`, this is about just data formatting?

Comment: I mean if you have to expose SOAP and REST interfaces for your services, then I would consider to use WCF...

Answer (score 0):

WCF is not the good choice for REST because it was not made for it, when they implemented it they did lots of bad hacks. you can see how they try to convert xml to josn [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/d925d870f3cb3f6acdb14e71522ece7054e2233b/System.Runtime.Serialization/System/Runtime/Serialization/Json/XmlJsonWriter.cs)

WCF is **NOT** deprecated, so powerful, and no framework can be comparable to it yet. but it is not for REST.